# Amount of error with CV.GLMNET

Tags: cross-validation, glmnet, mse

I'm predicting a continuous variable whose values are in $[0,1000]$. When I plot the cross validation of `cv.glmnet`, I obtain this :

[image: 1]

I don't understand why the CV MSE is so low (~0.1625). Why/how does this happen?